# mpcode and weight status could not be shown in output

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 //input
 string weight_st;
 int age, bmi = 0;
 char  gender, name[20], mpcode;
 double weight_kg = 0 , height_cm = 0, height_m = 0;
 
 //process
 cout<<"Please enter your name: ";
 cin>>name;
 cout<<"Please enter your age: ";
 cin>>age;
 cout<<"Please enter your gender (M/F): ";
 cin>>gender;
 cout<<"Please enter your weight in kg: ";
 cin>>weight_kg;
 cout<<"Please enter your height in cm: ";
 cin>>height_cm;
 
 //formula to calculate bmi
 height_m = height_cm * 0.01; //to convert centimeter to meter
 bmi = (weight_kg /(height_m*height_m) );
 
 //determine mpcode
 if(bmi>30)
 {
  if(age<40)
  {
   if(gender=='M' && gender =='m')
   {
    mpcode =='A';
    
   }
   else if(gender=='F' && gender =='f')
   {
    mpcode =='B';
   }
  }
  else if(age>=40) 
  {
   if(gender=='M'|| gender =='m')
   {
    mpcode =='B';
   }
   else if(gender=='F'|| gender =='f')
   {
    mpcode =='C';
   }
  }
 }
 else if(bmi<=30)
 {
  if(age>=40)
  {
   if(gender=='M'|| gender =='m')
   {
    mpcode =='B';
   }
   else if(gender=='F' || gender == 'f')
   {
    mpcode =='B';
   }
  }
 }
 else
 {
  cout<<"ERROR";
 }
 //determine weight_st
 if (bmi<18.5 || bmi >00.0)
 {
  weight_st == "underweight";
  cout<<weight_st;
 }
 else if (bmi>=18.5||bmi<=24.9)
 {
  weight_st =="healthy weight";
  cout<<weight_st;
 }
 else if (bmi>=25.0||bmi<=29.9)
 {
  weight_st =="overweight";
  cout<<weight_st;
 }
 else if (bmi>=30.0)
 {
  weight_st =="obesity";
  cout<<weight_st;
 }
 else
 {
  cout<<"ERROR";
 }
 
 //display staff information
 cout<<"*****************************************"<<endl;
 cout<<"Name : " <<name<<endl;
 cout<<"Age : "<<age<<endl;
 cout<<"Weight : "<<weight_kg<<endl;
 cout<<"Height : "<<height_cm<<endl;
 cout<<"Bmi : "<<bmi<<endl;
 cout<<"Mpcode : "<<mpcode<<endl;
 cout<<"Weight status : "<<weight_st<<endl;
 
 //determine retire age
 if (mpcode=='A'|| mpcode=='B')
 {
  cout<<"Retire at 60"<<endl;
 }
 else if (mpcode=='C')
 {
  cout<<"Retire at 55"<<endl;
 }
 else
 {
  cout<<"ERROR"<<endl;
 }
 
 return 0;
}
```

- this is the output i am getting

Please enter your name: james
Please enter your age: 20
Please enter your gender (M/F): m
Please enter yout weight in kg: 80
Please enter your height in cm: 145

---

Name : james
Age : 20
Weight : 80
Height : 145
Bmi : 38
Mpcode :
Weight status :
ERROR

- my expected output is

Please enter your name: james
Please enter your age: 20
Please enter your gender (M/F): m
Please enter yout weight in kg: 80
Please enter your height in cm: 145

---

Name : james
Age : 20
Weight : 80
Height : 145
Bmi : 38
Mpcode : A
Weight status : obesity
ERROR

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us some sample input, the expected output from that input, and the actual output from that input. Copy-paste text as text.

Comment: By the way: `int ..., bmi = 0;`? Should it really be an *integer* if you compare it to floating point values?

Comment: Enable more warnings in your compiler, and think about the difference between assignment (`=`) and equality comparison (`==`).